# Automatically creating User folders after registration

Tags: rules, users

I need to prepare a simple platform for uploading files for clients.

The procedure is simple:

1. user fills registration form and confirms e-mail address,
2. Drupal automatically creates a folder in system files via token e.g.
   sites/default/files/clients/upload/[account:name]
3. clients upload private files using Elfinder after log in.

Comment: Ok, but where is your problem on doing this? Creation of the folder? The File Upload?

Comment: i want creating folder automatically after user registration

Comment: not as answer, because i think there need to be better ways: you could create your own rule http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/06/29/drupal-7-create-your-own-rules-event/